# Splitting a configuration section (specifically a WCF section) into multiple config sections?

Tags: .net, wcf, configuration

I have this section in my web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors configSource="Configuration\Active\ServiceModelBehaviors.config" />
    <services configSource="Configuration\Active\ServiceModelServices.config" />
    <bindings configSource="Configuration\Common\ServiceModelBindings.config" />
    <client configSource="Configuration\Active\ServiceModelClient.config" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I want to add another client section with a different path to prevent configuration duplication:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors configSource="Configuration\Active\ServiceModelBehaviors.config" />
    <services configSource="Configuration\Active\ServiceModelServices.config" />
    <bindings configSource="Configuration\Common\ServiceModelBindings.config" />
    <client configSource="Configuration\Active\ServiceModelClient.config" />
    <client configSource="Configuration\Common\ServiceModelClient.config" /> <!-- this -->
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I understand that a section can appear only once. Is there anyway I can work this around? Like a partial section or something?

Comment: What do you want the result to be? What would happen with two config sources?

Comment: @nvoigt - I would expect to get a merge